# How to modify elements on a multi-level nested R list?

Tags: r, nested-loops, nested-lists

What I need to do is replacing all values of `type` vectors on the 4th level of the nested list `a` by the corresponding ones on the `transcodification` tibble and keeping the same structure for the rest of the list :

```
a = list(
    a1 = list(
      b1 = list(
        c1 = list(
          type = c(1,3),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        ),
        c2 = list(
          type = c(2,3,6),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        )
      ),
      b2 = list("foo")
    ),
    a2 = list(
      b1 = list(
        c3 = list(
          type = c(5),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        ),
        c4 = list(
          type = c(2,3,6),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        )
      ),
      b2 = list("foo")
    ),
    a3 = list(
      b1 = list(
        c5 = list(
          type = c(6),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        ),
        c6 = list(
          type = c(1,2,3,5),
          attribute1 = runif(3,0,1),
          attribute2 = list(d = rpois(1,1))
        )
      ),
      b2 = list("foo")
    )
  )
  
transcodification = tibble(origin = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                           replacement = c("Peter","Jake","Matthew","Suzan","Christina","Margot"))
```

Is it possible to do using `purrr` functions ?

Answer (score 3):

You can start with `purrr`'s `modify` function

```
modify_depth(a, 3, ~map(., ~str_replace_all(., transcodification %>% pull(2) %>% set_names(1:length(.)))))
$a1
$a1$b1
$a1$b1$c1
$a1$b1$c1$type
[1] "Peter"   "Matthew"

$a1$b1$c1$attribute1
character(0)

$a1$b1$c1$attribute2
character(0)


$a1$b1$c2
$a1$b1$c2$type
[1] "Jake"    "Matthew" "Margot" 

$a1$b1$c2$attribute1
character(0)

$a1$b1$c2$attribute2
character(0)



$a1$b2
$a1$b2[[1]]
$a1$b2[[1]][[1]]
[1] "foo"
```

But this will introduce additional list layers in b2, respectively.

If `"type"` is always on the first tree, than you can try without any further transformations

```
modify_depth(a, 3, ~modify_at(.,1, ~str_replace_all(., transcodification %>% pull(2) %>% set_names(1:length(.)))))
```

Or on each numeric vector

```
modify_depth(a, 3, ~modify_if(., is.numeric, ~str_replace_all(., transcodification %>% pull(2) %>% set_names(1:length(.)))))
```

For the replacement we will use `stringr`'s `str_replace_all` while the replacement is done using a named vector like this:

```
transcodification %>% pull(2) %>% set_names(1:length(.))
      1           2           3           4           5           6 
"Peter"      "Jake"   "Matthew"     "Suzan" "Christina"    "Margot"
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, this is really helpfull !

However, i didn't realize my problem has one more tricky situation : each b2 aren't lists but vectors (you can get this by modifying `b2 = list()` with `b2 = runif(1,1,2)` 

Any of your solutions works with this new list. I get an error : 
Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a character to a double.

Any help ?

Comment: this `modify_depth(a, 3, ~modify_at(., 1, ~str_replace_all(., transcodification %>% pull(2) %>% set_names(1:length(.)))))` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (an extension of base `rapply()`).

The list elements with name `"type"` that need to be replaced are specified in the `condition` argument and the replacement function is specified in the `f` argument:

```r
library(rrapply)

ans <- rrapply(
        object = a, 
        condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "type",
        f = function(x) transcodification$replacement[x],  
        how = "replace"
)

str(ans)

#> List of 3
#>  $ a1:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c1:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr [1:2] "Peter" "Matthew"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.37 0.685 0.783
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 2
#>   .. ..$ c2:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr [1:3] "Jake" "Matthew" "Margot"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.251 0.613 0.301
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 1
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "foo"
#>  $ a2:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c3:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr "Christina"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.548 0.233 0.623
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 2
#>   .. ..$ c4:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr [1:3] "Jake" "Matthew" "Margot"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.618 0.828 0.685
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 0
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "foo"
#>  $ a3:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ c5:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr "Margot"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.424 0.156 0.79
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 0
#>   .. ..$ c6:List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ type      : chr [1:4] "Peter" "Jake" "Matthew" "Christina"
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute1: num [1:3] 0.941 0.16 0.649
#>   .. .. ..$ attribute2:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ d: int 1
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "foo"
```

---

NB: if the name `"type"` also occurs on other list levels, the `condition` can be made more precise by evaluating only the `"type"` elements at the *fourth* level of the list:

```r
ans <- rrapply(
        object = a, 
        condition = function(x, .xname, .xpos) .xname == "type" && length(.xpos) == 4L,
        f = function(x) transcodification$replacement[x],  
        how = "replace"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Joris C. solution is a cleaner `rrapply` approach but here is another take that I think gets you what you want. I was thinking would an `unlist`/`relist` type option work here:

```
library(rrapply)
library(tidyverse)
#restructure transcodification 
transcodification_named <- transcodification$origin %>% setNames(transcodification$replacement)
#unlist list into dataframe (instead of using base::unlist)
a_unlist <- rrapply(a, how = "melt")
```

Then replace type values in the dataframe as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564960/4083743):

```
a_unlist <- a_unlist %>% 
  mutate(value = map2(value, L4, ~ if(.y %in% 'type') 
    unname(coalesce(setNames(names(transcodification_named), 
                             transcodification_named)[.x], as.character(.x))) else .x))
#then reconvert to a list (instead of base::relist which needs list skeleton object)
a_relist <- rrapply(a_unlist, how = "unmelt")
a_relist
```